# Using ANTLR with java and maven to parse expressions and convert them to SpEL

Tags: spring, parsing, java-8, maven-3, antlr4

I need to use ANTLR and convert a given expression to its spring expression language equivalent. Below is a simple set of sample input and output expressions.

Input: (account='233AS77') AND (code='SIMP') AND (cost=270)

Output SpEL: (account.equalsIgnoreCase("233AS77")) and (code.equalsIgnoreCase("SIMP")) and (cost eq 270)

How do I go about this? Can someone please help me get started? I am familiar with SpEL but completely new to ANTLR and it's concept. An example, snippet or reference to a solid article to understand ANTLR would be amazing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am answering this quite late, primarily for posterity (and my recently rekindled interest in ANTLR).

I put together a simple but complete [implementation](https://github.com/octavian-nita/so/tree/master/so-59078288) of the problem sketched in the original question, including a viable, Maven-based project setup.

There are several ANTLR introductions around, but only a few are worth your while, beginning with the [official documentation](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/index.md) (along with [The Definitive ANTLR 4 Reference](https://pragprog.com/titles/tpantlr2/the-definitive-antlr-4-reference/), which is not outdated, despite its publication date) and continuing with Strumenta's [ANTLR Mega Tutorial](https://tomassetti.me/antlr-mega-tutorial/) and Baeldung's short, but [to-the-point tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/java-antlr). Granted, in my experience using ANTLR, it's usually more straightforward to follow and understand someone else's examples than to write your own grammar and language application. Also, you can't really just jump in and write a "language application" without doing a bit of reading first (albeit with ANTLR, not a lot is required). I will try to summarize the gist of the matter below and walk you through my implementation.

ANTLR (or the *ANTLR tool*, to be more precise) is a *parser generator*. That means you feed it a *grammar*, a formal textual description of the structure of all the possible sentences in the language you're defining; it then generates (in one or several so-called *target languages*, of which Java is one) the code of a *parser* capable of *analyzing* programs written in that "input" language. When invoked by your application's code, the generated parser tries to *match* its input data (not necessarily textual, but could be binary as well) against the grammar rules it was built from, and upon success, it builds a *parse tree*, a structured representation of the input. Then, your application can *walk* that tree using a *custom visitor* (check out a refresher on the [Visitor design pattern](https://blogs.oracle.com/javamagazine/post/the-visitor-design-pattern-in-depth)) or the *ANTLR runtime*-provided `ParseTreeWalker`. In the former case, your custom visitor extends a base visitor the ANTLR tool generates along with the parser and overrides methods corresponding to various parse tree nodes of interest to handle successful matches. With the latter option, you implement *listener* methods to handle tree nodes that interest you (see the observer/listener design pattern). Note that you also get a generated base listener in this second case, outlining the available methods the `ParseTreeWalker` will call.

More precisely, you need to:

1. Integrate the *ANTLR tool* in your application build pipeline; you can, undoubtedly, execute the tool occasionally against your grammar to generate the parser source code before building the application. However, the far better practice is to integrate parser source code generation in your build pipeline. With Maven (or Gradle), you can [use the antlr4-maven-plugin](https://github.com/octavian-nita/so/blob/eceb4f4be86dd7051d48a06d21e055bc0ad830fe/so-59078288/pom.xml#L58), whose defaults are mostly okay. Note that you must specify both the `-package` (ANTLR) option and the output directory to generate the parser in a file structure according to its package definition (assuming you define a package in the grammar).
2. Add the *ANTLR runtime* as a [compile-time dependency](https://github.com/octavian-nita/so/blob/eceb4f4be86dd7051d48a06d21e055bc0ad830fe/so-59078288/pom.xml#L50) of your project. It contains classes that the generated parser, visitors, listeners, and even your code can use (e.g., error handling strategies, etc.).
3. Write a grammar for the language you want to define; a grammar is a set of lexical and syntactic rules that define how the parser will try to match its input. In this case, you need a [grammar for the simple expression](https://github.com/octavian-nita/so/blob/eceb4f4be86dd7051d48a06d21e055bc0ad830fe/so-59078288/src/main/antlr4/Expr.g4) you want to translate into a SpEL expression. Note that, in general, there is no ONE grammar that does the job, but several that might work. Especially when you start with the language definition, you often reorganize the grammar rules; hence, there is a need to integrate parser generation in your build pipeline.
4. Write a listener or a custom visitor to handle parse tree nodes of interest. By "handling," I mean translating the parse tree structure into another language, [like in our use case](https://github.com/octavian-nita/so/blob/eceb4f4be86dd7051d48a06d21e055bc0ad830fe/so-59078288/src/main/java/eu/objectivum/so59078288/Expr2SpELListener.java), generating code, interpreting the expression, etc.
5. [Glue together](https://github.com/octavian-nita/so/blob/eceb4f4be86dd7051d48a06d21e055bc0ad830fe/so-59078288/src/main/java/eu/objectivum/so59078288/Expr2SpEL.java#L17) the basic objects involved in creating, customizing, and invoking the parser instance and, subsequently, walking the resulting parse tree to generate the desired output.